# What happens to the arguments passed to execve?

Tags: c, exec, system

I understand that calling `execve` will completely wipe the text, data, bss and stack of the calling program and replace it with that of the callee program.

My question is this:

What happens if we pass a `char` array that was allocated on the heap to `execve` as one of its arguments? The `char *` itself resides on the stack, but all of the individual `chars` are on the heap. Wouldn't execve wipe this data? How would the new program receive its arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `execve` syscall will make a copy of the args and put them in the new program's address space.

You can see this on line 1586 here

```
1581         bprm->exec = bprm->p;
1582         retval = copy_strings(bprm->envc, envp, bprm);
1583         if (retval < 0)
1584                 goto out;
1585 
1586         retval = copy_strings(bprm->argc, argv, bprm);
1587         if (retval < 0)
1588                 goto out;
1589 
1590         retval = exec_binprm(bprm);
1591         if (retval < 0)
1592                 goto out;
```

*(from http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c)*

Comment: So it performs a deep copy? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it copies the contents of each argv *(and envp)* string.

Comment: BTW, the `copy_strings()` function starts at line *454* in that link I included -- it's a pretty complicated function.